# How to do json mapping on multiple json object with same key

Tags: android, jsonschema2pojo, gson

I've been trying to use GSON and [JsonScheme2Pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org) to map my json object.

So far I've created this class.

```
public class MPayTransaction {

@SerializedName("mp_request_type")
@Expose
private String mpRequestType;
@SerializedName("status_code")
@Expose
private String statusCode;
@SerializedName("amount")
@Expose
private String amount;
@SerializedName("chksum")
@Expose
private String chksum;
@SerializedName("pInstruction")

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     The mpRequestType
 */
public String getMpRequestType() {
    return mpRequestType;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param mpRequestType
 *     The mp_request_type
 */
public void setMpRequestType(String mpRequestType) {
    this.mpRequestType = mpRequestType;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     The statusCode
 */
public String getStatusCode() {
    return statusCode;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param statusCode
 *     The status_code
 */
public void setStatusCode(String statusCode) {
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     The amount
 */
public String getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param amount
 *     The amount
 */
public void setAmount(String amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     The chksum
 */
public String getChksum() {
    return chksum;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param chksum
 *     The chksum
 */
public void setChksum(String chksum) {
    this.chksum = chksum;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     The pInstruction
 */
public int getPInstruction() {
    return pInstruction;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param pInstruction
 *     The pInstruction
 */
public void setPInstruction(int pInstruction) {
    this.pInstruction = pInstruction;
}

}
```

and then i called the class this way:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
MPayTransaction mPayTransaction = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MPayTransaction.class);
```

This is working and I only need to call for example `MPayTransaction.getAmount()` to get the value of amount;

I've been wondering, how do I map multiple json object? let say the previous json string is like this :

```
{
"mp_request_type": "donePayment",
"status_code": "00",
"amount": "1.10",
"chksum": "23259ef7e03266ada789bf5a30465469",
"pInstruction": 0
}
```

and then how about this :

```
{
"mp_request_type": "donePayment",
"status_code": "00",
"amount": "1.10",
"chksum": "23259ef7e03266ad23430465469",
"pInstruction": 0
},
{
"mp_request_type": "donePayment",
"status_code": "100",
"amount": "13.10",
"chksum": "23259ef7e03g2r32fa30465469",
"pInstruction": 0
}
```

how do i get the value of 2nd amount which is `13.10` from `MPayTransaction.getAmount()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use ArrayList<>, for example 
jsonString :

```
[{
"mp_request_type": "donePayment",
"status_code": "00",
"amount": "1.10",
"chksum": "23259ef7e03266ad23430465469",
"pInstruction": 0
},
{
"mp_request_type": "donePayment",
"status_code": "100",
"amount": "13.10",
"chksum": "23259ef7e03g2r32fa30465469",
"pInstruction": 0
}]
```

parse this string to ArrayList<>:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<MPayTransaction>>(){}.getType();
Collection<MPayTransaction> collObj = gson.fromJson(jsonString, collectionType);
ArrayList<MPayTransaction> arrayList = new ArrayList<MPayTransaction>(collObj);
```

then get the value of 2nd amount:

```
arrayList.get(1).getAmount()
```

Comment: Worked for me. I used json "java.lang.reflect.Type" and "com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken".